# Kickstart installing RPM without dependencies

Tags: centos, rpm

I have a project that is currently using kickstart to automatically install a CentOS distribution with various RPM packages.
I need now to add a new RPM in the installation process, I have added it to my %packages section but it doesn't work because of its dependencies.
The problem is that the options `%packages --resolvedeps` and `%packages --ignoredpes` are no longer supported (the script doesn't work).

Are there any workaround to get a RPM to be installed without dependencies throught kickstart?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? The RPM, presumably, lists the dependencies it actually needs to work so not having them will make the RPM package not work correctly. What version of CentOS is this?

Comment: @EtanReisner I'm using CentOS 6.0 (I cannot upgrade). I need to install clamav-0.98-4.1, the packages needed are libssl.10 and libcrypto.10 wich I have through openssl, but I still have an error when installing (I don't know why, I'm not a Linux expert), but it is working when forcing with `--nodeps` (I have tried to install it manually after CentOS instalaltion and its working).

Comment: On a system where you installed it manually and it is working what does `rpm -V clamav` say? Where did this clamav package come from?

Comment: The package come from http://pkgs.repoforge.org/clamav/ (file clamav-0.98.4-1.el6.rf.i686.rpm) the command `rpm -V --nodeps clamav` is resulting `S.5....T. c /etc/freshclam.conf` didn't know if this is really helpful...

Comment: I didn't say `--nodeps` on that command. Run it again without that. (I don't know if it matters but it might.)

Comment: Oh, and if you *really* meant you are on 6.0 (and not 6.6 or 6.7) then your system is **full** of gaping security holes.

Comment: I should also point out that clamav is available in EPEL and you might have better luck with that package than with one from repoforge.

Comment: I cannot issue `rpm -v` with nodeps it's asking me to fix the dependencies, but that's may not be a problem I guess... concerning the use of CentOS 6 (yes I'm on 6.0), long story short I must use this version. I will try to use a different repo, maybe this one is kind of corrupted

Comment: Capital `V` not lowercase `v`. `rpm -V clamav`. It should not care about missing dependencies. And like I said CentOS 6.0 is **full** of **gaping** security holes and should **absolutely not** be on the public internet. It **will** get compromised.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience that is so risky to install without dependencies that I would not try. Normally programmers (the good ones) try very hard to reduce the need for dependencies for the sake of the program itself. --Nodeps, might generate unpredictable instabilities. Hope that works for you case anyway.